# Making a query for all objects that don't have `None` for a certain field

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model `Chair` with a nullable field `.datetime`.

I want a query that will get all chairs that have some value in `.datetime`, no matter what it is, as long as it's not `None`.

I know how to do this by building a `Q` object and negating it, but is there a less cumbersome way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Chair.objects.filter(datetime__isnull=False)
```

It's interesting you mention negating the Q object - people usually learn the other way around :)